# Latest email received date in python from outlook

Tags: python, email

I am extracting data from email which is sent on a daily basis and I have to create a column named data received date while doing some manipulations on the data via python.

Comment: show some code, be more precise. I guess you have several milestone in your project. 1) Manage to connect to your email with script. 2) navigate through the INBOX, get the right emails and the data inside 3) play with the dataframes.      Maybe this can help https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/reading-emails-in-python

Answer (score 0):

First, you should create a variable called "today"

```
from datetime import date      
today = date.today()
```

And then you can populate a new column on your df

```
# add column to pandas df with the following format "dd/mm/YY"
dataframe['todays_date'] = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```